# Send a parameter depending of the button that I click Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, kendo-ui

I need to send a paramether depeding of the button that I click(edit or create) in my main view to a partial view(pop-up), Which in turn sends this parameter of the controller(brings the filtered list).

This is my controller

```
public ActionResult docList(string type){
        var business = new mymodelBusiness();

        return Json(from item in business.GetList(Id, UsrId, type)
                    select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Value = Convert.ToString(item.Id),
                        Text = item.Cod + ", " + item.Nom //+ item.usrNom
                    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is the dropdownlist that I need in my partial view(pop-up)

```
    <div class="form-group select-crud col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <p>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.novId)</p>
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(p => p.novId)
              .Name("clcList")
              .DataTextField("Text")
              .DataValueField("Value")
              .Filter("contains")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      .Read(read => read.Action(""docList", "myController", new { action = variable });//here's the problem. I don't know how to receive the variable
                  });
              })
              .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "form-control" })
        )
    </div>
```

and This is my main view, only the grid, I need the aditional data function what is doig nothing yet

```
      @(Html.Kendo().Grid<myModel>
        ()
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;text-align:left" })
        .Name("grid")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Command(command =>
            {
            columns.Bound(c => c.Cod).Width(200);
        })
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        .ToolBar(toolbar =>
        {
        toolbar.Template(@<text>
        <button class='btn btn-success btn-sm k-grid-add' data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Create">
            <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus'></span>
        </button>            
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book "></span>
        </button>
        </text>);
        })
        .ColumnMenu()
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("docCustom").Window(w => w.Width(700)))
        })
        .Events(events =>
        {
            events.Cancel("onCancel");
            events.Remove("onRemove");
            events.Save("onSave");
            events.Edit("onEdit");
            events.DataBound("onDataBound");
        })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler").RequestEnd("onRequestEnd"))
        .PageSize(10)
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.masterId))
        .Read(read => read.Action("AccionRead", "myController"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("AccionCreate", "myController"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("AccionUpdate", "myController"))
        .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("AccionDelete", "myController"))
        ).AutoBind(false)
    )
```

event onEdit:

```
        function onEdit(e) {
            //Implement the event handler for Edit
            if (e.model.isNew()) {
                $('.k-window-title').html('New');
                $('.k-grid-update').html('<span class="k-icon k-add"></span> Create');
            }
        }
```

Comment: You need to post the java script code of your events. You already have an event for edit, called 'onEdit', which can easily pass the parameter you want. I'm not sure if you have any events for create too

Comment: so what parameter are you trying to pass to the new partial view?

Comment: "Create" or "Edit", something like this:                                             .Read(read => read.Action(""docList", "myController", new { action = variable }))